# adding markers and polylines in realtime

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, google-polyline

How to add more markers and draw more polyline on maps using a realtime data from another activity ?
I'm using the tutorial of the maps. 
but i can only add markers in the oncreate and can't pass realtime data from another activity

how can I add more than one marker the feeds the lat and long from another activity periodically

Answer (score 0):

Truly depends on how to pass the data from the other activity to the one that uses Google Maps v2 API. The easiest way I can think of is using [Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object)) (links automatically to the docs (toJson method))

Gson allows you to serialize an object `into its equivalent Json representation` of Gson. From my experience, the object shouldn't contain non generic types such as other objects. This could be an example of your marker object.

```
class MarkerObject {
    public String name = "";
    public String snippet = "";
    public double lat = 0.0;
    public double lng = 0.0;
    public String markerImg = "";

    public MarkerObject() {}
}
```

To serialize it into a Json string and pass it through an intent, do this:

```
MarkerObject exampleOfObject = new MarkerObject();
exampleOfObject.name = "Test Marker";
exampleOfObject.snippet = "Description/snipper woooh!";
exampleOfObject.lat = 1.0;
exampleOfObject.lng = 1.0;

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourMapActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("exampleMarker", new Gson().toJson(exampleOfObject));
startActivity(intent);
```

And read it out in your map Activity in your `onCreate()` method.

It could look like this at the bottom of the method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String jsonMarker = intent.getStringExtra("exampleMarker", "");

if(jsonMarker != "") {
    MarkerObject exampleOfObject = (MarkerObject) new Gson().fromJson(jsonMarker);

    MarkerOptions exampleMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    exampleMarkerOptions.title(exampleOfObject.name);
    exampleMarkerOptions.snippet(exampleOfObject.snippet);
    exampleMarkerOptions.position(new LatLng(exampleOfObject.lat, exampleOfObject.lng));

    // Change 'map' into the variable name of your GoogleMap object.
    map.addMarker(exampleMarkerOptions);
}
```

I haven't tested it myself however, according to the docs, it should work. Feel free to edit this answer if you wish to add/modify/delete something.

Comment: I'm passing the data from the main activity to the maps and other activities using global variables in public class. and I'm able to receive data correctly in the maps class.
the issue is that I can't add markers except initially when the maps activity created.
and I can't add marker when I get new lat and long from the sending class.

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue now what you exactly mean. Is it like permanently adding markers, is that what you wish to have? Once you add a marker, it should stay on the map?

Comment: I'll rephrase 
I have a google maps activity
I want to add markers or polyline according to new input lat and long coming from another activity

so initially I draw the map
then with a handler check the change of value of the lat and long variables coming from the main activity by globalvariable.getlat()
I can only draw one marker which is created when I call the maps activity.
how can I add more than one marker the feeds the lat and long from another activity periodically ??